# How to set the color of a TextView in Android?

Tags: android

In the string.xml file I use the following tag

```
<color name="mycolor1">#F5DC49</color>
```

If I use

```
 textview1.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
```

it works, but

```
 textview1.setTextColor(R.color.mycolor1);
```

is not working.

How can I use the color defined in the XML file?

Answer (score 83):

`TextView.setTextColor()` takes an int representing the color (eg. 0xFFF5DC49) and not the resource ID from the xml file. In an activity, you can do something like:

```
   textView1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor))
```

outside of an activity you'll need a `Context` eg.

```
   textView1.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor))
```

Answer (score 22):

```
 textView1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F5DC49"));
```

without resources

Answer (score 14):

## **`context.getResources().getColor`** is Deprecated.

You need to use **[ContextCompat.getColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context,%20int))**, which is part of the **Support V4 Library** (so it will work for all the previous API).

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color);
```

You will need to add the Support V4 library by adding the following to the `dependencies` array inside your app build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1' # or any version above
```

If you care about theming, the documentation specifies that the method will use the context's theme:

> Starting in M, the returned color will be styled for the specified
> Context's theme