# changing table row font color

Tags: android

I have made a high score `activity` for my game. i used table row for the output of the scores. My question is that how can i change the color of the fonts in my table row because i cannot see what's the output.

Here's my layout code:

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/data_table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        >

        <TableRow android:visibility="invisible" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="#"
                android:textColor="#000000" />


            <TextView
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="Score"
                android:textColor="#000000" />


            <TextView
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="Player"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Here's the color of my output in high score `activity`.

[image]

How will i change the gray one to black?

here's how i add the table:

```
{
            TableRow tableRow= new TableRow(this);

            ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(position);

            TextView idText = new TextView(this);
            idText.setText(row.get(0).toString());
            tableRow.addView(idText);


            TextView textOne = new TextView(this);
            textOne.setText(row.get(1).toString());
            tableRow.addView(textOne);

            TextView textTwo = new TextView(this);
            textTwo.setText(row.get(2).toString());
            tableRow.addView(textTwo);

            dataTable.addView(tableRow);
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please show how you are adding the table rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a text color when you create the `TextView`s programmatically, because Android will use its default (grey) color otherwise. Black is `0xFF000000`.

```
TextView textOne = new TextView(this);
textOne.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
textOne.setText(row.get(1).toString());
tableRow.addView(textOne);
```

Note that you may want to [use a color resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668958/how-to-set-color-for-the-textview-in-android) for this to keep it consistent with your other `TextView`s.