# Highlight TextView when clicked programmatically

Tags: android, textview

I dynamically generate TextViews which work like buttons. Now i want to highlight them when they get pressed. Something like change Text color or background color. 
I have tried to use selector, but it doesn't work.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ffffff"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

Here my loop for creating the TextViews.

```
int z = 0;
    for (MOKGenericDataItem d : data) {
        if (d.getButtonText() != null) {
            final int pagePosition = z;
            TextView btn = new TextView(getActivity());
            btn.setId(z);
            final int id_ = btn.getId();
            btn.setText(d.getButtonText());
            btn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 30);
            btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            mLineareLayoutViewPagerButtons.addView(btn);

            btn1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(id_));
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pagePosition,false);
                }
            });
        }
        z++;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you setting the selector to the TextView?

Comment: I don't see where you set the selector as the TextView's background ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all your this line is creating ambiguity as you are taking a variable name as btn1 (which is relating it to button)and you are taking a reference of `TextView`,

```
 btn1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(id_));
```

Anyways,**Go step by step,**

- create an xml like `label_bg.xml` like the following in the `drawable` folder:

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
          <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_color"
                android:state_pressed="true" />    
          <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_color" />
      </selector>
  ```
- In `values` folder create another `xml` like the following,named as `labelcolors.xml`

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
  <drawable name="pressed_color">#7ec0ee</drawable> <!--custom color for pressed state -->
  <drawable name="normal_color">#00FFFFFF</drawable> <!--transperent color for normal state -->
  </resources>
  ```
- Now set the background of the label as `label_bg.xml`

  ```
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/yourlabel"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="760dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="515dp"
      android:background="@drawable/label_bg"   <!--like this-->
      android:text="LabelText"
      android:textSize="20dp" />
  ```

---

**as you are dynamically adding the views so you need to set the background for your each textView programatically** .For that call `setBackgroundResource()` on the `textview` object created and set `label.xml` as background

Comment: Thanks, works. Now it changes color to white just when i press, could i change it so it stays white?

Comment: do you maybe have a solution for this? that it stays white until i press another texview?

Comment: I guess you was looking for a click like functionality,check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668958/how-to-set-the-color-of-a-textview-in-android) till i  come back to you

Comment: what are we to do when we want to also set the state's color dynamically?? Is it possible?

Comment: [Have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4602929/681929) @inverted_index

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a class implements with `OnTouchListener` and Detect touch `Motin`. `ACTION_DOWN`, change text color and `ACTION_UP` change it's default color according to your requirement.

**Code:**

```
public class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF); // white
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4a4a4a")); // lightblack
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now set TouchListener using

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener());
```