# Change text's background clolor in onTouch event to the corresponding tags

Tags: java, android, webview, touch-event

The following is my `strings.xml` file. I am trying to change the text'x background color corresponding to the tags. For eg: when `OnTouch` event happens the first tag's text should get highlighted. I had gone through the following link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400354/highlight-textview-when-clicked-programmatically). It is changing the entire background color. How to implement this. Please help me.

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">WebView</string>
<string name="html">
<![CDATA[

<p>ఒక,పెద్ద,పోలీసు,అధికారి,ఒక,మేధావుల.సభలో,హైద్రాబాద్‌లో,ప్రసంగిస్తూ,ప్రజలలో,హింసా.ప్రవృత్తీ,దౌర్జన్య
దృక్పథం,పెరిగి,పోయిందన్నారు.పోలీసు,బలగానికికూడా,ఇదే,వర్తిస్తుందని,ఆయన,చెప్పినా.ప్రజలలో,ఆ,ప్రవృత్తి,తీవ్రం
కావడంచేతనే,పోలీసులలోనూ.దాన్ని,ప్రతి,క్రియారూపంలో,చూస్తామనేది,ఆయన,వాదన,సారాంశం.</p>

<p><b>मैं विद्यापीठ के चारों साल छात्रावास में रही.</b></p>
<p><b>होरीराम,ने,दोनों,बैलों,को,सानी-  पानी,दे,कर,अपनी,स्त्री,धनिया,से,कहा,गोबर,को,ऊख,गोड़ने,भेज,देना.मैं,न,जाने,कब,लौटूँ.जरा,मेरी,लाठी,दे,दे.धनिया,के,दोनों,हाथ,गोबर,से,भरे,थे.उपले,पाथ,कर,आई,थी.बोली,अरे,कुछ,रस-पानी,तो,कर,लो.ऐसी,जल्दी,क्या,है,होरी,ने,अपने,झुर्रियों,से,भरे,हुए,माथे.को,सिकोड़,कर,कहा,तुझे,रस-पानी,की,पड़ी,है.मुझे,यह,चिंता,है,कि,अबेर,हो,गई,तो,मालिक.से,भेंट,न,होगी.असनान-पूजा,करने,लगेंगे,तो,घंटों,बैठे,बीत,जायगा.इसी,से,तो,कहती,हूँ,कुछ,जलपान,कर,लो,और,आज,न,जाओगे,तो,कौन,हरज,होगा,अभी,तो,परसों,गए,थे.</b></p>
<p><b>प्रसिद्द कबीर अध्येता, पुरुषोत्तम अग्रवाल का यह शोध आलेख, उस रामानंद की खोज करता है.किन्तु आधुनिक पांडित्य,एक जुलाहे कबीर का गुरु होने से, बल्कि दोनों के समकालीन होने से भी, इनकार करता है.उस पर, इन चार का गहरा असर है.इसे कई बार, मंचित भी किया गया है.यहाँ प्रस्तुत है, हिन्दी कवि कथाकार, तेजी ग्रोवर के के मार्फ़त किए गए अनुवाद के कुछ अंश.मूल से, में लाने का काम, मीना कंदसामी ने किया है, से हिन्दी अनुवाद, गिरिराज किराडू ने.उस्ताद बिस्मिल्लाह खान, भारतीय संगीत ही नहीं, समूचे कला संसार में, एक विलक्षण उपस्थिति रहे.अपने व्यक्तित्व, वाद, दोनों से वे, शास्त्रीय संगीत में, एक नए थे.उन पर दो हिन्दी का गद, इस फ़ीचर में शामिल है.</b></p>
<p><b>प्रसिद्द कबीर अध्येता, पुरुषोत्तम अग्रवाल का यह शोध आलेख, उस रामानंद की खोज करता है.किन्तु आधुनिक पांडित्य,एक जुलाहे कबीर का गुरु होने से, बल्कि दोनों के समकालीन होने से भी, इनकार करता है.उस पर, इन चार का गहरा असर है.इसे कई बार, मंचित भी किया गया है.यहाँ प्रस्तुत है, हिन्दी कवि कथाकार, तेजी ग्रोवर के के मार्फ़त किए गए अनुवाद के कुछ अंश.मूल से, में लाने का काम, मीना कंदसामी ने किया है, से हिन्दी अनुवाद, गिरिराज किराडू ने.उस्ताद बिस्मिल्लाह खान, भारतीय संगीत ही नहीं, समूचे कला संसार में, एक विलक्षण उपस्थिति रहे.अपने व्यक्तित्व, वाद, दोनों से वे, शास्त्रीय संगीत में, एक नए थे.उन पर दो हिन्दी का गद, इस फ़ीचर में शामिल है.</b></p>
<p>एक हफ्ते में सात दिन होते हैं.</p>
<p><b>मैं विद्यापीठ के चारों साल छात्रावास में रही.</b></p>
<p>एक हफ्ते में सात दिन होते हैं.</p>
]]>
</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            return true;
        } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Saim I will check and let you know.
The above code is to change textview's text color. I want to change webview's text color.